# Icinga2: can't find notification history in db

Tags: icinga2

I wan't get icinga2 notification history from db.
 like timestamp1 object1 state->DOWN, call notifycommand1 send to user1.

main table icinga_notifications is ok.
but nothing in icinga_contactnotificationmethods and icinga_contact_notificationcommands.

Also, no data in icinga_logentries.

Do I make any mistake in config or what config can make this occur?

icinga2 version: r2.8.4

My ido_mysql config:

```
library "db_ido_mysql"

object IdoMysqlConnection "ido-mysql" {
  host = "xxx"
  port = xxx
  user = "xxx"
  password = "xxx"
  database = "xxx"
  table_prefix = "icinga_"
  instance_name = "default"
  enable_ha = true
  cleanup = {
    acknowledgements_age = 1209600
    commenthistory_age = 1209600
    contactnotificationmethods_age = 1209600
    contactnotifications_age = 1209600
    downtimehistory_age = 1209600
    eventhandlers_age = 1209600
    externalcommands_age = 1209600
    flappinghistory_age = 1209600
    hostchecks_age = 1209600
    logentries_age = 1209600
    notifications_age = 1209600
    processevents_age = 1209600
    servicechecks_age = 1209600
    statehistory_age = 1209600
    systemcommands_age = 1209600
  }

}
```

https://icinga.com/docs/icinga1/latest/en/db_model.html

Document db model can't match mine.